# ¿como ordenar el código CSS?

Tags: css

Estoy revisando un código de administrador de archivos de un CMS y cuando descargo un .CSS al momento de abrirlo (VSC) todo el código me sale en una sola linea, hay una forma o comando de poder acomodarlo, identarlo, etc?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Te sale en una sola linea cuando lo abris donde? probaste abrirlo en otro lado?

Comment: si, me sale en una sola linea todo el código, lo abro en VSC y sublime y sale de la misma forma

Comment: Entonces estara todo en una sola linea.. si no tiene saltos de linea, no van a aparecer...

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + P -> Formatear Documento en VSC

Comment: Si te sale en una sola línea es porque está "minificado". El CSS se *minifica* para reducir el peso del fichero y por lo tanto, incrementar su velicidad de carga. La manera de hacerlo es quitando espacios, saltos de línea, tabulaciones... Que tan solo aportan legibilidad. Todos los CMS tienen alguna manera de darle formato.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá encontré una página para "desminificar" archivos: https://unminify.com/.

Solo hay que copiar todo el contenido de tu archivo `CSS`, pegarlo ahí y descargarlo todo ya indentando automáticamente.